# How to insert C# string into JSON string

Tags: c#, json

How to insert string `sUsername` to `myEmail` and `sPassword` to`myPassword`?

`sUsername` and `sPassword` are from the login form.

I'm just learning JSON, can I make a JSON variable and fill it with `sUsername` and `sPassword` values?

Here is my code:

```
public void login(string sUsername, string sPassword)
{
    var httpWebRequest = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://atsiri.online/api/v1.php");
    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
    httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

    using (var streamWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        string json = @"
        {
            ""type"":""login"",
            ""condition"":{
                ""0"":{
                    ""key"":""email"",
                    ""value"":""myEmail""
                },
                ""1"":{
                    ""key"":""password"",
                    ""value"":""myPassword""
                }
            }
        }";

        streamWriter.Write(json);
        streamWriter.Flush();
        streamWriter.Close();
    }

    var httpResponse = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
    using (var streamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Any reason you want to do this manually rather than using Json.NET? I'd *strongly* advise you to use a JSON library of some kind rather than building the string yourself.

Comment: FYI There is a widely used library for de/serializing JSON in .Net at https://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need Json.NET if you want to construct your JSON, you can use [anonymous type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types) like this:

```
var obj = new
{
    type = "login",
    condition = new Dictionary<string, object>()
    {
        { "0", new { key = "email", value = "myEmail" } },
        { "1", new { key = "password", value = "myPassword" } }
    }
};

string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are having an invalid json string, you should format it properly (refer to this [link](http://easyonlineconverter.com/converters/dot-net-string-escape.html))

Make a raw json first then use that [link](http://easyonlineconverter.com/converters/dot-net-string-escape.html) to have escaped json string

You can append the string using this code:

```
var json = "{   \"type\": \"login\",    \"condition\": {        \"0\": {            \"key\": \"email\",         \"value\": \"" + sUsername + "\"        },      \"1\": {            \"key\": \"password\",          \"value\": \"" + password + "\"     }   }}";
```

[image]

=======UPDATED=====

As per Jon Skeet's advice to use JSON library to build your JSON object for your request.
Here is a sample code that is based in your situation. I use Newtonsoft.Json library from NuGet.

1.Create a class:

```
public class LoginRequest
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string,string> [] condition { get; set; }
}
```

2. Serialized object using Newtonsoft.Json library:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

var login = new LoginRequest
{
    Type = "login",
    condition = new Dictionary<string, string>[]

    {
        new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            {"key" , "email" },
            {"value", sUsername }
        },
        new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            {"key" , "password" },
            {"value", password }
        }
    }
};            
var jsonx = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(login);
```

[image]

> Notice that it is very easy and more maintainable to use JSON library
>   than to create a raw JSON string.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the variable into the string

```
string json = @"
        {
            ""type"":""login"",
            ""condition"":{
                ""0"":{
                    ""key"":""email"",
                    ""value"":"+ sUsername +"
                },
                ""1"":{
                    ""key"":""password"",
                    ""value"":"+ sPassword +"
                }
            }
        }";
```

Comment: have you tried using 'type' in place of ""type"". Thats how I would have formatted it

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is the simplest, but don't forget to write an @ again after each variable.
So the string becomes:

```
string json = @"
    {
        ""type"":""login"",
        ""condition"":{
            ""0"":{
                ""key"":""email"",
                ""value"":"+ sUsername +@"
            },
            ""1"":{
                ""key"":""password"",
                ""value"":"+ sPassword +@"
            }
        }
    }";
```